# MongoDB, do another count after a group count

Tags: mongodb

I'm kinda new with mongodb. i made a query to count child with same parent (parentid), the query looks like this:

`db.Child.aggregate([
    {
        "$group" : 
        {
            _id:"$parent", count1:
            {
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    }
])`
And the result looks like this:
[image]

The next step i need to do is count how many 1s, 2s, 3s, etc in `count1` field above. Is it possible to do another count like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is get the total number of `count1` values, you could add another `$group` and another accumulator as follows:

```
db.Child.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: "$parent",
        count1: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: "$count1",
        count2: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```